# How I can make the StreamPlot of this differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, piecewise

[image][image: I don't know how to plot this]

I need the StreamPlot of this differential equation but I don't know how.

```
dp/dt = 0.4 p(1 - p/30), 0 <= t < 5 and 0.4 p (1 - p/30) - 0.25 p, t > 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Piecewise` to define your function:

```
StreamPlot[{1, Piecewise[{{0.4 p (1 - p/30), 0 < t <= 5},
                          {0.4 p (1 - p/30) - 0.25 p, t >= 5}}]}, {t, 0, 10}, {p, -5, 5}]
```

[image: stream plot]

Comment: As noted in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133381), it seems `Piecewise[]` no longer plays nice with `StreamPlot[]`; nevertheless, a re-expression in terms of e.g. `UnitStep[]` will work: `StreamPlot[{1, 0.4 p (1 - p/30) - 0.25 p UnitStep[t - 5]}, {t, 0, 10}, {p, -5, 5}]`

Answer (score 0):

This is really a visualization of J.M.;s comment.

```
sol[a_, r_] := 
 p /. First@
   NDSolve[{p'[t] == 
      0.4 p[t ] (1 - p[t]/30) - 0.25 p[t] UnitStep[t - 5], p[r] == a},
     p, {t, 0, 10}]
Manipulate[
 Show[
  StreamPlot[{1, 0.4 p (1 - p/30) - 0.25 p UnitStep[t - 5]}, {t, 0, 
    10}, {p, -5, 5}],
  Plot[Evaluate@sol[a, r][t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  ],
 {a, -1, 1},
 {r, 0, 10}
 ]
```

[image]